# Remove Image With Certain Width and Height

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, image

I created a site that automatically uploads image posts to my WordPress site ([Tattoo.ws](http://tattoo.ws)) from Reddit via IFTTT.com.  My issue is this: some of the posts don't have images, and I'd like to have those removed automatically.

If you go to the site, you'll see some of the images are generic, which states "image not found".  Until now, I've been manually deleting posts which have the generic "image not found" picture, but it's taking way too long to continue to do this.

I'm looking for something, whether it be PHP or JS, which will remove these images by either targeting the url from which they come from, or the image size.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're going to need to share some code. We have no idea how these things actually function.

Comment: What type of code do you need?  Is it not possible to create a simple JS function that hides a certain image by width?  Or is there a function that can at least target them, and add a CSS class to it, which I could then use to hide the images?

Comment: You can simply [hide the images with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33109903/1326147) as I've answered. However, if your goal is to completely remove those posts with those placeholders images from the DB, you can do it exclusively through the RDBMS you are using. If it's MySQL, phpmyadmin has a global search functionality that allows you to detect all of them in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery on that site, and I noticed that all your "image not found" images have a pattern, according to these samples:

- http://tattoo.ws/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/no_image_card68.png
- http://tattoo.ws/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/no_image_card70.png
- http://tattoo.ws/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/no_image_card71.png

Therefore you can simply do in the main page (where your listing is):

```
<script>
jQuery('article img.wp-post-image').each(function() {
  var curImg = jQuery(this);
  if(curImg.prop('src').indexOf("no_image_card")>-1){
    console.log(curImg.prop('src')); //reports the image to be hidden
    curImg.parents("article").hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

Basically, I'm hiding the article associated to that post with "no image". I tested this in your [site's page 5](http://tattoo.ws/page/5/) and it works.

If you want to completely eliminate all the posts from the DB, then you can do a search by the `"no_image_card"` in your posts table (if that's where they are stored).

Comment: Thank you!  One quick question, is there a way to not display them?  Like css display:none type deal?  The script does hide the images, but it still leaves the "spot" on the grid open, whereas display:none removes it completely.

Comment: @BillyW oh then change it to `curImg.parents("article").css('display', 'none')` :)